# Set Clickable Area of an Image in Corona

Tags: coronasdk

I was trying to create a tic-tac-toe-like game but this time the board is a collection of hexagons in a rhombus shape. See image below:

[image]

Each hexagon is an image:

[image]

And each image has its own event listener. I am having problem with the clickable area, every time I click the lower two hexagons from the top. The top hexagon receives the tap event. I suspect that its because the PNG image has some portion occupying the lower two hexagons. Please give me recommendations.

Comment: Just a quick question. does the image have the spaces like the one you presented? if so try trimming the image with no spaces. On Photoshop: image -> Trim

Comment: Thank you! It's working now :)

Comment: No probmate. Goodluck Coding